# How to use TO_CHAR function functionality in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named Transaction. I need to use TO_CHAR function sql server. But there is no TO_CHAR function Is there any conversion function in SQL Server for TO_CHAR?

This is the query i want to write in SQL Server.

`select * from Transactions where to_char(Transaction_Date_Time, 'yyyy') like '2022';`

Here are the table Transactions

| Transaction_ID | Transaction_Amount | Transaction_Date | Reciver_ACC_No | Account_No |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TRA2022072500001 | 60000 | 2022-06-15 14:28:60 | ACC2022050005 | AC20210500001 |
| TRA2022072500005 | 3000 | 2022-06-20 13:37:40 | ACC2022050006 | AC19990300007 |

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: You can use like this select FORMAT(getutcdate(),'dd-MM-yyyy').Is there any specific reason to use convert function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to compare the year then use `DATEPART` function

```
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, Transaction_Date_Time) = 2022
```

Even when the data type is string and do not have date format to cast then use `CHARINDEX` function:

```
Where CHARINDEX('2022', Transaction_Date_Time) > 0
```

Comment: Your answer works well. Thanks a lot for the help. Also, may I know how to perform this query using the `CONVERT` function?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to compare dates by year is to use ranges. This would apply to Oracle also. This allows you to hit indexes properly.

For example:

```sql
WHERE Transaction_Date_Time >= '20220101' AND Transaction_Date_Time < '20230101'
```